# Problems with Tornado Web Server filedownlaod

Tags: python, web, webserver, tornado

tornado web server.

i have a question.

how can i download file through tornado web server?

this is my code.

```
def get(self):
    data = self.xls_f()
    self.set_header('Content-Type', 'application/apk')
    self.set_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=%s' % 'test.apk')
    f = file('test.apk') 
    self.write(f.read())
    self.finish()
```

1. I'v get file with unreadable content like "asdfafasfd ㅁ ㅁ ㅇㄴㅁㄹㅁㄹㄴ"
   maybe this('\n') is unreadable.
2. apk, image file etc. i can download but file size is 0k or 1k.

how can i many kind of file(image, apk, etc) download tornado web server?

i want to example source code. plz.

Comment: On what operating system are you running this?

Answer (score 4):

below code is for download file from tornado server, which i used in my app for csv file download. it may help you.

```
def post(self,filename):
    print('i download file handler : ',filename)

    ifile  = open(filename+".csv", "r")
    self.set_header ('Content-Type', 'text/csv')
    self.set_header ('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='+filename+'')
    self.write (ifile.read())
```

Comment: You need to add self.finish() otherwise the html markup sometimes leaks into the generated csv file .Thanks for the code BTW

Answer (score 0):

For binary files, you should do:

```
f = file('test.apk', 'rb')
```